# como pegar parametros da url com django rest framework usando ModelViewSet?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Estou fazendo assim:

**Views:**

```
class Teste(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ModelBla.objects.none()
    http_method_names = ["get"]

    def list(self, request, parametro):
        print(parametro)
        return Response()
```

**Router:**

```
router.register('teste', views.Teste)
```

quando eu vou para /teste/algum_parametro recebo:

```
"detail": "Not found."
```

Answer (score -1):

Nesse caso você deve passar os parâmetros via args na url.

Por exemplo:

.... teste?parametro1=abcd&parametro2=efgh&parametro3=ijkl

Com isso, você poderá acessar estes parametros dentro do método list do seguinte modo:

parametro1 = self.request.query_params.get('parametro1')
parametro2 = self.request.query_params.get('parametro2')
parametro3 = self.request.query_params.get('parametro3')